# ng-include con templateCache en google chrome extension (Angular 1.5.8)

Tags: angularjs, extensión-google-chrome

Estoy desarrollando una extension para google chrome con angular.

todo funciona bien, pero cuando quiero utilizar templateCache con ng-include, este intenta buscar la ruta dentro de la carpeta de la extension y jamas busca en el templateCache.

```
<ng-include src = " 'ViewHTML' "></ng-include>
```

el codigo que utilizo para cargar la vista en el templeteCache...

```
$templateCache.put("ViewHTML","<h1>Working</h1>");
```

siempre uso templateCache, pero solo deja de funcionar cuando lo intento usar con `<ng-include>`

> la versión de angular utilizada es 1.5.8

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un par de errores en el código

1. La directiva es [`ng-include`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) no `ng-included`
2. Los nombres de las vistas deben coincidir. Si escribiste 'ViewHTML' debes referenciarlo siempre así. En tu código tienes 'viewHTML' con minúscula. La sintáxis de [`$cacheFactory`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory) es `put('key', value)` por lo que las llaves deben ser idénticas.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('TestCtrl', function($templateCache) {
    $templateCache.put("ViewHTML", "<h1>Working</h1>");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="TestCtrl">
  <ng-include src=" 'ViewHTML' "></ng-include>
</div>
```

Comment: fue solo un error de posteo que ya edite, el tema de que la key tiene que ser identica ya se aplicaba, lo mismo que para el tag `<ng-include>`, aun asi no funciona, sigue buscando como una ruta y no dentro del templateCache

Comment: @MoisésGodoy Fíjate que te acabo de postear un ejemplo funcionando en el snippet. Los `ng-include` no funcionan en los stack-snippets a menos que estén en `$templateCache` así que imagino que el problema es que el código que está actualizando la `$templateCache` no se está ejecutando. Con el código que has posteado y sin más información es imposible saberlo.

Comment: puse la version de angular citada para que se viera mejor, en versiones antiguas de angular se que funciona bien.. en este caso deje la version aclarada, es la `1.5.8`, en cambio en tu ejemplo usas las `1.2.23`

Comment: @MoisésGodoy Esa es la máxima versión que te deja escoger el snippet. Actualizé manualmente la versión y funciona igual. La versión de angular no tiene que ver en esto.

Comment: tienes razon, debe ser el contexto, porque la consola me indica que intenta buscar el archivo y como ng-include de cierta manera dejar de responder no sigue buscando en el templateCache, aun no entiendo porque adopta este comportamiento, si cuando pruebo de forma normal, si ng-include no encuentra el archivo fisico automaticamente deberia seguir en buscar dentro de templateCache

Comment: @MoisésGodoy O quizas el código que ejecuta `$templateCache.put` no se ejecuta por alguna razón o lo hace luego que llamas a `ng-include` como te expliqué anteriormente. El hecho que sea una extensión de Chrome no cambia la forma en la que `$templateCache` funciona ya que este es un simple almacén clave/valor en memoria.